# Is "Allah" hidden in the ayah frequences in the Koran?

Tags: quran, allah, names

I found a hidden name of Allah while I was experimenting with the numerical part of the Koran's order.
The results can been seen in the attached diagram:

[image]

What have I done? In short, nothing special. I just put each number value of each surah and ayah in a coordinate system and 
joined the outer points with a line. Now, with a little imagination you can see the name of Allah. But the more interesting aspect is
that all points *(all chapters)* are located within the corpus of Allah's name (btw: the green points are muhkam verses, the red points mutashabih verses).

Is it already known that such a name exists? Is this a coincidence? 
Could that be the reason why the Koran is ordered by length of chapters?
Or is it only an imagination?

Comment: Could you show us the *exact* methodology you used to get the ayahs and suras?

Comment: I am curius what made you draw the alif (A) . Because it is not following the rules given to join the outer points as the other points. Another question is how you determined the x and y offset. in x (sura number ) we see that 0 - 120 is way longer than Y (aya number). How did you determine that length? Also the diagram displays an extra L (lam) . What is that supposed to be? On the other hand I dont think the message of the Quran is to hide hidden messages. It's clear guidance not hidden guidance.

Comment: Pretty good demonstration of the human mind's inclination to seek patterns, whether there are any to be found or not.

Answer (score 4):

Maasha Allah. Hidden wonders are many in Quran. This shows the perfection in every way. As far as your question is concerned, It may or may not be the reason why length of chapters are arranged in order. Until Allah subhanu wa ta'la says, we cannot come to a conclusion. For He knows the best. Allah says in Quran

> “This Qur’an is not such as can be produced by other than Allah, on the contrary it is a confirmation of (revelations) that were sent before it, and a full explanation of the book, wherein there is not doubt from the Lord of the worlds”. (10:37)
>
> “... A book which We have sent down unto you with full of blessings so that they may meditate on its signs and that man of understanding may receive admonition”. (38:29).

The one you found could be one of the signs

> “We have revealed for you (O men) a book in which there is a message for you, will you then not understand”. (21:10).

The message could be hidden like how you found out or straight forward.

All praise be to Allah.. Lord of the worlds.